# Can't read multi-dimensional array(Table)

Tags: lua, roblox

```
    Module = {}
    tempData = {Visit = false, Stats = {Name = 'No Name', Levels = 0, XP = 0, XP2 = 10},
            Hats = {Basic = true, NightShade = false},
            Robes = {Basic = true, NightShade = false},
            Boots = {Basic = true, NightShade = false},
            Swords = {Basic = true, NightShade = false}
            }



        function Module:ChangeLook(player, category, name)
            tempData[player][category][name] = true
        end

       --[[ function Module:readStats()
            for k, v in pairs(tempData['Stats']) do
                print(k)
                print(v)
                wait()
            end
        end
        function Module:readHats()
        for k, v in pairs(tempData['Hats']) do
                print(k)
                print(v)
                wait()
        end
        end

    --These two works, but it's not effective if I have to make each function to read different array(table)]]

   --[[ function Module:ReadAll()
       for i = 1, #tempData do
           for k = 1, #tempData do
               print(tempData[i][k])
           end
       end
```

this function is what i'm working on, but I can't figure out what's wrong?
I'm trying to read the whole array(table) without using separate function to read each individual.]]

```
    return Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in your case:

```
tempData = {
  Visit = false,
  Stats = {Name = 'No Name', Levels = 0, XP = 0, XP2 = 10},
  Hats = {Basic = true, NightShade = false},
  Robes = {Basic = true, NightShade = false},
  Boots = {Basic = true, NightShade = false},
  Swords = {Basic = true, NightShade = false}
}

function ReadAll()
  for k,v in pairs(tempData) do
    if type(v) == 'table' then
      for k2, v2 in pairs(v) do
        print(k..":",k2,v2)
      end
    else
      print(k..":",v)
    end
  end
end

ReadAll()
```

Check if its a table and print it with **key - value** pairs instead of **index - value**.